# javascript not print / arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I keep running into an error on my javascript code for why this wont print..

can someone kind of proof read this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I would post the HTML, but i'm only importing the script into the html in the .html file and boilerplate such actions in there.

```js
// JavaScript Document
//var $ = function (id){
//return document.getElementById(id);
// hooty hoo

var money = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var newEntry;
var out;


//1
var $ = function(id) { 
return document.getElementById(id); 
};

window.onload =function()
{

var button = document.getElementById("Calculate");
button.addEventListener("click", calc, false);
newEntry = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
out = document.getElementById("output");


};


//2
var calc = function() 
{
var result = 200 + (parseFloat(.09 * newEntry));
//result.mathfloor(result/100);
result.toFixed();
 //var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputVal").value);
if(result<0){
return;
}
  

  
if(result >= 200 && result<=299)
++money[0];
if(result >= 300 && result<=399)
++money[1];
if(result >= 400 && result<=499)
++money[2];
if(result >=500 && result<=599)
++money[3];
if(result >=600 && result<=699)
++money[4];
if(result >= 700 && result<=799)
++money[5];
if(result >= 800 && result<=899)
++money[6];
if(result >= 900 && result<=999)
++money[7];
if(result >= 1000)
++money[8];

Display();
document.getElementById("inputVal").value = "0";

  
  
  
  //3
var Display = function(){
$("output").value = "gross salary pay/n"+
"$200-299/t" + money[0] + "0" +
"$300-399/t" + money[1] +"0" +
"$400-499/t" + money[2]+ "0" +
"$500-599/t" + money[3]+ "0" +
"$600-699/t" + money [4] + "0" +
"$700-799/t" +money[5] + "0" +
"$800-899/t" + money[6]+ "0" +
"$900-999/t" + money[7] +"0" +
"$1000+/t" + money[8]+ "0" ;
};
  
  
  
window.addEventListener("load",calc,false);   
};
```

```html
<html> 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Salary</title>
    
    <script src="ArraySalary.js"></script>

</head>


 <form action = "#">
<p>Gross Sales :
<input id = "inputVal" type= "number">
<input id = "Calculate" type = "button" value="submit"></p>


<textarea name= "output"
rows = "15" cols = "19"> </textarea>







</form>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there an actual error which says something, or an error as in you don't know why it's not doing what you think it should do?

Comment: I don't understand why it's not printing.. like its blank ; i'll post the HTML also

Comment: Could you convert it into a jsfiddle or stack's snippet? (Click the fifth button, from the left, in the second column.

Comment: FYI, using `$` as a function to look up an id is likely going to cause readability headaches/confusion later on given its generally used by `jQuery`. Probably nicer just to stick with native `document.getElementById` given you're doing it in a number of places already anyways

Comment: sorry I don't feel like explaining but go throw the code I fixed it  here  http://jsbin.com/dedupowato/edit?js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id="output"` in html because you are using `$("output").value` which calls the function

```
var $ = function(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

```js
// JavaScript Document
//var $ = function (id){
//return document.getElementById(id);
// hooty hoo

var money = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var newEntry;
var out;


//1
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

window.onload = function() {

  var button = document.getElementById("Calculate");
  button.addEventListener("click", calc, false);
  newEntry = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
  out = document.getElementById("output");


};


//2
var calc = function() {
  var result = 200 + (parseFloat(.09 * newEntry));
  //result.mathfloor(result/100);
  result.toFixed();
  //var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputVal").value);
  if (result < 0) {
    return;
  }



  if (result >= 200 && result <= 299)
    ++money[0];
  if (result >= 300 && result <= 399)
    ++money[1];
  if (result >= 400 && result <= 499)
    ++money[2];
  if (result >= 500 && result <= 599)
    ++money[3];
  if (result >= 600 && result <= 699)
    ++money[4];
  if (result >= 700 && result <= 799)
    ++money[5];
  if (result >= 800 && result <= 899)
    ++money[6];
  if (result >= 900 && result <= 999)
    ++money[7];
  if (result >= 1000)
    ++money[8];






  //3
  var Display = function() {
    $("output").value = "gross salary pay/n" +
      "$200-299/t" + money[0] + "0" +
      "$300-399/t" + money[1] + "0" +
      "$400-499/t" + money[2] + "0" +
      "$500-599/t" + money[3] + "0" +
      "$600-699/t" + money[4] + "0" +
      "$700-799/t" + money[5] + "0" +
      "$800-899/t" + money[6] + "0" +
      "$900-999/t" + money[7] + "0" +
      "$1000+/t" + money[8] + "0";
  };

  Display();
  document.getElementById("inputVal").value = "0";

  window.addEventListener("load", calc, false);
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Salary</title>

  <script src="ArraySalary.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <p>Gross Sales :
      <input id="inputVal" type="number">
      <input id="Calculate" type="button" value="submit">
    </p>


    <textarea id="output" name="output" rows="15" cols="19"></textarea>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```